# Android Text Messaging

Tags: android, eclipse, sms, messaging

Right now, i'm dealing with android text messaging but on these few lines it turns error saying that `(sendBtn,message,numberTxt) cannot be resolved or its not a field.` Can anyone help me to fix the error?

```
sendSMS = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendBtn);
msgTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.message);
numTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numberTxt);
```

This is my full code :

```
package com.hp.message;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.view.View;


public class Main extends ActionBarActivity {

    Button sendSMS;
    EditText msgTxt;
    EditText numTxt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        sendSMS = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendBtn);
        msgTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.message);
        numTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numberTxt);

        sendSMS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                String myMsg = msgTxt.getText().toString();
                String theNumber = numTxt.getText().toString();
                sendMsg(theNumber, myMsg);
            }
        });
    }

    protected void sendMsg(String theNumber, String myMsg) {
        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(theNumber, null, myMsg, null, null);
    }
}
```

Main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.hp.message.Main" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

And also I already taken the permission by adding  in the AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Post code of `main.xml`

Comment: Have u taken Permission?

Comment: does youy `main.xml` has the buttons defined?

Comment: @SilentKiller already include it below...see edited post

Comment: @PratikButani yea,already...as written there (edited post)

Comment: If this is your whole main.xml, you're missing sendBtn, and both textviews, that's why all 3 findViewById fail. You need to add Button and those 2 TextViews in your layout file.

Comment: @MockingJay you are missing 2 textviews and button as well as not giving the id of the above textview ... you also have to give id in order to findViewById work ....

Comment: Use this one http://www.androidsnippets.com/sms-library-in-android

Comment: Can u post your Logcat

Comment: Thanks all @SilentKiller but i have another question y in my AndroidManifest.xml turns error?


        <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

Comment: @Haresh Chhelana but i have another question y in my AndroidManifest.xml turns error?


        <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `main.xml` must be like this then and then only you can bind `sendBtn, message, numberTxt` to the Activity file.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.hp.message.Main" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/numberTxt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sendBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

**main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/numberTxt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:hint="phone no"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="message"
        android:gravity="top|left"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sendBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Send"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```